# How this is possible? Test loss is under train

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

I got this graph for my loss.

As you can see the distance between the two graphs is so much!

[image]

Can we say it shows bias is large and it's underfitting?

Is this thing that I just said true or isn't true? So what's the reason?

Sorry if my question isn't good. I'm super new in this field and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This is likely a programming issue where you mixed up the training and testing data. Most likely, the red is the training loss and the blue is the testing.

Comment: @Dave thanks. Red one is test loss and blue one is train loss. Can you please help me what happens when it looks like this? What's the reason can be?

Comment: What's your underlying task? How large are the train/test splits? If you didn't mix up your splits, the other main programming bugs to look out for are (1) a bug in your train/test split or (2) a bug in your loss calculation. It's possible but unlikely that this comes down to essentially sampling luck.

Comment: @chang_trenton thanks. It's actually not mine. Can't we evaluate a model only by looking at the plot?  Can you explain more? I actually couldn't understand much! Thanks

Comment: if you train a model with dropout, during training the model underperforms because of the masking, instead during training it uses all the neurons... most likely whatever model that loss is coming from had a very heavy dropout rate